# What is the worker_aio_requests directive in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

Assuming I am using a modern Linux distribution like Ubuntu 14.04 and assuming that I am using the epoll() system call, what does worker_aio_requests do?

The docs say:

> If you are using aio with the epoll connection processing method, this
>   directive sets the maximum number of outstanding asynchronous I/O
>   operations for a single worker process.

When I first read that, I thought it meant that for a given worker process, when a connection arrives, during the lifetime of connection, it checks if it is read or write ready and if not, then it puts it in the event queue. Worker process continues accepting connections. When that one specific connection is ready for read or write, kernel notifies with system call and the worker handles the data. So this directive would refer to the number of oustanding I/O operations permitted in the event queue.

But I don't think that's what this does, because I think that's what the `worker_connections` directive of the Event Module does. So I am confused by what `worker_aio_requests` and `worker_connections` do?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine sending hundreds of images on one page across a persistent http connection. One client connected to the worker but it does many I/Os. It would be nice to not block on those reads so the worker doesn't have to wait.

[IBM developerWorks article on AIO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-async/) has a good outline of async vs. blocking.

In this case nginx uses at least two interfaces to I/O, the epoll() to accept the connection and AIO for things like serving files.  There is implementation differences to listening to many file descriptors versus queuing up lots of I/O to some other file descriptors.

Reading ngx_epoll_module.c, worker_aio_requests is fed to io_setup() system call. This results in the advertised set up of that many async operations per worker.

Normally one uses libaio for this, although nginx seems to bypass that and use the system call. This difference in interface and some other quirks resulted in multiple configuration directives exposed, so you can tune both worker connections and concurrent I/Os.